# In flutter is there a way to rebuild the current tab when the active tab bar button is pressed

Tags: flutter, tabs

In `TabBar` when a different a non-active `Tab` is pressed all the `Tab`s appear to rebuild, but when the active `Tab` is pressed nothing happens.  Is it possible to get the active `Tab` to rebuild when the active `Tab` is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TabBar`'s `onTap`:

```
TabBar(
  tabs: [...],
  onTap: (index) {
  },
)
```

Comment: thanks im so used to onPress thats all i search for